# Customizing fixed pipeline projection matrix

Tags: opengl

I am working with [NV Path extension](https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering) which forces using of fixed pipeline transformations. Now, while for view and model matrices I just roll my own and load those via:

```
glMatrixPushEXT(GL_MODELVIEW);
glMatrixLoadfEXT(GL_MODELVIEW, value_ptr(viewmodel) );
```

I have issues with perspective matrix FOV. The fixed method for creation persp matrix is this:

```
glMatrixLoadIdentityEXT(GL_PROJECTION);
glMatrixFrustumEXT(GL_PROJECTION, -aspect_ratio, aspect_ratio, -1, 1, nearF, farF);
```

but it doesn't allow passing a custom FOV. So it probably creates some default FOV based on  l ,r ,b ,t params of the method above. Can I use:

```
glMatrixLoadfEXT(GL_PROJECTION, myProjectionMatrix);
```

to load a custom projection matrix without using glMatrixFrustumEXT?

**UPDATE:**

As some peopled pointed out, I can load projection matrix the same way I do with model view.But I found that my custom projection never looks the same as when using glMatrixFrustumEXT(). Probably FOV calculation is different. Anybody knows how glMatrixFrustumEXT calculates the FOV?

Comment: Huh? You're already using `glMatrixLoadfEXT` successfully for the modelview matrix. What makes you think this won't work for any other matrix, too, like the projection matrix? Why not just try it and see what happens (hint: it will do what you and anybody else would expect it to do)? By the way, please try not to carry your somehow weird spacing convention over into written natural language.

Comment: By the way, if you wouldn't use direct state access you could also use `gluPerspective` to your advantage, which probably does what you need. But like said, if you have the matrix anyway, just use it.

Comment: I  wasn't sure because I ave no idea how glMatrixFrustumEXT works .I did try using glMatrixLoadfEXT but I have some issues with FOV which is somehow different from what I am after. "By the way, please try not to carry your somehow weird spacing convention over into written natural language" -Say what?

Comment: @MichaelIV: "*Say what?*" He's talking about your tendency to put spaces *before* punctuation instead of after. Spaces come after in most cases.

Comment: Ah , ok , thanks for the head-ups. English isn't my native language ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas: I guess MichaelIV is French hen, where putting spaces before punctuation is perfectly normal.

Comment: No guys , I am Israeli and in Hebrew it all works differently :P

Comment: @datenwolf What ? You mean in French the spacing rules are entirely different ? And I thought it was at least common practice in all *"Western"* languages ,surprising indeed .

Comment: @ChristianRau: I only know about it, by having read the documentation of loads of TeX packages; in this case the package used to introduce French language support and the typographical conventions used then.

Comment: @ChristianRau I see you have  your period after "surprising  indeed " positioned incorrectly too.  ;)

Comment: @MichaelIV My whole comment was incorrectly punctuated on purpose (this rule applies to question tags and commas as well, of course). But at least you noticed the period case, though that is unfortunately the one most people get. It's the question tag that many seem to see as a concept completely different from a normal period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using glFrustum or glMatrixFrustumEXT does allow to specify the FOV, and you actually do so. As you define the points on the near plane, and the distance of the near plane, you implicitely define the fov, both vertical and horizontal.

Look at the old gluPerspective function:

```
gluPersepctive(fov_y, aspect, zNear, zFar)
```

This would generate a symmetrical frustum with the given vertical FOV of fov_y as follows:

```
top=tan(fov_y/2.0) * zNear; // assuming fov_y in radians here
bottom=-top;
left=bottom*aspect;
right=-left;
glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
```

In your code, you are simply specifying a vertical FOV of 2*atan(1/nearF)

Comment: Really? So near plane value defines the fov?  Good to know.

Comment: Well, to make this clear: the near plane defines the fov in your code. Usually, one would define both FOV and distance to near plane and calculate the rest of the frustum parameters accordingly.